# Outlook REST API and mail archive action

Tags: outlook, office365api, outlook-restapi

We would like to have the "Archiving" capabilities in our application using Outlook REST API (see the button I am referring to in OWA).

From the documentation, I see no possibility for knowing which folder is indeed the "Archive folder".

[image: Archive button]

Can it be done ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Archive button moves items to a pre-selected folder in the mailbox. If you query for mail folders using the beta endpoint, you'll see that the archive folder has a `WellKnownName` property set to `archive`. So you can get it directly by doing:

```
GET https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/me/mailfolders/archive
```

This is separate from the archive mailbox some organizations setup. In that setup messages are archived to a secondary mailbox assigned to the user. Currently the REST API doesn't support archive mailbox access.

Comment: Using my debugger I found out that the folder that you choose for Archiving is now marked with `WellKnownName = "archive"` see screenshot http://imgur.com/a/41jD3. Unless I am mistaken this is way to create the archive button, right ?

Comment: Hrmm. Maybe this is something different than the archive mailbox. Let me verify.

Comment: Updated answer. Sorry about that, I didn't fully understand what you originally asked!